# is it possible to update and save a pfobject from a query using parse?

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to do this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query whereKey:@"playerName" equalTo:@"Dan Stemkoski"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {

           // THis is the part that isn't working
            PFObject *pTeam = objects[0];
            [pTeam setObject:@"new team name" forKey:@"team"];
            [pTeam saveInBackground];
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
}];
```

When I update the found query object and save, it is not saved to the server.

Is what I am doing possible and if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error? The code looks OK, but you could run into throttling issues. Please provide more info than "it is not saved".

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one, it works for me.

```
        PFObject *pTeam = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:"GameScore" objectId: [object[0] objectId]];

        [pTeam setObject:@"new team name" forKey:@"team"];
        [pTeam saveInBackground];
```